# How to work with the jButton grid as a two dimensional array in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton

I have made a grid of 8*8 jButton. I want to use those buttons in a two dimensional array. How I'll proceed?

Comment: By asking a question on SO each and every time you get stuck, rather than doing any research on the Internet for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You proceed the same as you would with any other array of arrays:

```
JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[cols][rows];
```